# How to keep reference before assign in their value

Tags: c#

```
scanner = new Scanner(ref vm, handler);
vm = new ViewModelScanner(ref scanner);
```

I need to have that the scanner always can get and set instance of `ViewModelScanner`, and the `ViewModelScanner` always can get and set instance of `Scanner` from the current class.

Comment: You need a wrapper for this.
Put your Scanner in a wrapper and put your ViewModelScanner in a separate wrapper.
Changing the value within the wrapper changes it everywhere where the *wrapper* is referenced

Comment: @TomR Did you mean you want `scanner` and `vm` be [class data members](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/members) instead of [local variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables#local-variables) ? But what do you mean by "*keep reference before assign in their value*" ? Do you want to keep all previous assignments so all instances in a list ?

Comment: @Olivier Rogier  I want `scanner` and `vm` to be modifiable inside each other from the current class

Comment: Is the reference reciprocal (scanner has a reference to vm and vm has a reference to scanner) or may there exist the case where scanner1 has a reference to vm1 and vm1 has a reference to another Scanner (scanner2)?

Comment: There are two classes inside the current ScannerDriver class. It has two properties - ViewModelScanner and Scanner. In the constructor of the ScannerDriver class, I create objects of these classes and want methods inside one class to affect the other. For example: `vm` changes something in `scanner` and the change is visible in the current class (ScannerDriver) Is it possible to do this?

Comment: @TomR Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273) (don't just change your question to "How").

Comment: You don't need "ref" here (if both are classes, not structs). You still have a copy of the *reference* you want. OK, this doesn't solve the unassigned issue you already have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it as simple as holding a reference of each other in the class?

```
void Main()
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner();
    ViewModelScanner vms = new ViewModelScanner();
    scanner.ViewModelScanner = vms;
    vms.Scanner = scanner;
}

public class Scanner
{
    public ViewModelScanner ViewModelScanner{get;set;}
}

public class ViewModelScanner
{
    public Scanner Scanner{get;set;}
}
```

Now you can use properties and methods from the other class instance.

Comment: That is a mutual [aggregation](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/uml-aggregation-vs-composition/) between two objects, called [circular dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency). Generally anti-pattern: [How to solve circular dependency](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/306483/how-to-solve-circular-dependency) & [Circular dependencies between classes: why they are bad - how to get rid of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43023400/circular-dependencies-between-classes-why-they-are-bad-and-how-to-get-rid-of-th)